# Bash file: how to open the correct version of Matlab

Tags: bash, matlab

I am trying to run a Matlab code in the HPC of my university. The code is submitted using `qsub` and a `bash` file.

In order to use Matlab R2019b, I have been instructed that: *To make use of Matlab R2019b add the following to the top of your script after the scheduler flags*

```
export PATH=/username/local/matlab/bin:$PATH
```

I'm having troubles in doing that. Could you check my bash file and tell me what is wrong? At the moment, my bash file opens Matlab R2015b (instead of Matlab R2019b). (Note: in place of username I have put my actual username)

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=4G
#$ -l tmem=4G
#$ -l h_rt=24:0:0
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y

#Run 3 tasks where each task has a different $SGE_TASK_ID ranging from 1 to 3
#$ -t 1-3

#$ -N try
date
hostname


#Output the Task ID
echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

export PATH=/username/local/matlab/bin:$PATH


matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main_1; ID = $SGE_TASK_ID; main_2; exit"
```

Comment: Sounds like maybe there are multiple MATLABs on the path. Try specifying the path to the matlab R2019b executable directly

Comment: I have tried `export PATH=/username/local/matlabR2019b/bin:$PATH` but it still opens Matlab R2015b. I think the issue is with the `matlab` command in front of `-nodisplay`. How do I check whether the path is correct or not?

Comment: Anyhow, if I type on the terminal `cd /home/username/local` it tells me:
`-bash: cd: /home/username/local: No such file or directory`

Comment: `/home/username/local` is not the same as `/username/local`. Also, please verify that you are expected to replace "username" with your username. It seems strange to me that MATLAB would be installed in your user directory rather than in a shared directory.

Comment: Could this not be solved simply by launching MATLAB with the full path to version R2019b, e.g. `/usr/bin/matlab2019 -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main_1; ID = $SGE_TASK_ID; main_2; exit"`?